# Shifting the index of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n\cdot n\cdot (n-1)\cdot x^{n-2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

I want to shift the index of 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n\cdot n\cdot (n-1)\cdot x^{n-2}$$
to start at $n=0$. If I expand this series I get:

$$a_2\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot x^0+a_3\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot x^1+\cdots$$

But if I start simply at $n=0$ without doing any modification, I get:

$$a_0\cdot 0\cdot (-1)\cdot x^{-2}+a_1\cdot 1\cdot0\cdot x^{-1}+a_2\cdot2\cdot1\cdot x^0+\cdots$$

which is the same as the series above, because the first $2$ terms are $0$, so I tought I could just write it like this:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\cdot n\cdot (n-1)\cdot x^{n-2}$$

but My book writes it as the following:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n$$

what's happening?

Comment: Both sums are the same because of the reason that you name, that the first two terms are equal to $0$.

Comment: Don't start at $0$, just apply directly the shift $n\mapsto n+2$ and the result will follow. (Note that with this shift the new index stars at $0$, as wished)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. In the book, they just "shifted" the whole expression.

They just replaced $n$ with $n+2$.
So instead of starting with $n=2$ they start with $n=0$, but they use $n+2$ in the expression, so it is the same as just using $n=2$ in the original formula.

If you expand both series, you will see it is the same.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing happens !

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\cdot n\cdot (n-1)\cdot x^{n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n$

Comment: Please improve this answer (-1)